# enum('yes', 'no') vs tinyint -- which one to use?

Tags: mysql, boolean, tinyint

What's the best practice for fields that hold true/false values?

Such columns can be defined as enum('yes','no') or as tinyint(1). Is one better/faster than the other?

Is it better to use enum('1','0') vs. enum('yes','no') (i.e., does it write 'yes' or 'no' as a string to every row so the database storage size gets bigger)?

Comment: A boolean is basically a tinyint(1).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Also, `ENUM` is a non-standard MySql extension. You should avoid it, especially if you can achieve the same results in a standard way.

Answer (score 15):

avoid enum from this [reasons](http://www.brandonsavage.net/why-you-should-replace-enum-with-something-else/)

> The bottom line is that ENUM has its
>   place, but should be used sparingly.
>   The model should enforce the
>   constraints, not the database; the
>   model should handle interpreting raw
>   data into useful information for your
>   views, not the database.

Answer (score 12):

`BOOLEAN` type is there for a reason. It is indeed a `TINYINT(1)` but since it's there, it must be the recommended way.