# Storing a Yes / No radio button into a MySQL database

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, codeigniter

I've seen a Yes/No form radio buttons value be stored/saved in a couple different ways. I wonder which way is better and why? This is for a PHP/MySQL application with a typical Yes/No question as part of a form.

1.) Store it as 1, 0 or null. 1 being Yes, 0 being No and null being not answered.

2.) Store it as Yes, No, null. Assume a language conversion can be made.

3.) Use 1, 2 and null so as to better distinct the values.

Thanks, Jeff

Edit: I also must mention that most of the issues have been arising due to jQuery/JavaScript and the comparisons and $() bindings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since MySQL has a BOOLEAN type, but it's simply an alias of TINYINT. I recommend against it because the equal sign in PHP == would not distinguish 0 from the lack of value. You'd always need to use triple equal === and it would be easy to make mistakes.

As for your options:

1. This seems the natural choice with PHP, but then you've to be careful to distinguish 0 from the lack of value, so I wouldn't recommend it.
2. I would not recommend this one.
3. Possible, but the assignment to 1 and 2 is somewhat arbitrary and might be difficult to remember and read in code.

What I usually do, is use "Y", "N" and NULL if needed, in a CHAR(1) field, it reads well in code and doesn't create problems.

Comment: @Codemonkey updated my answer with your suggestion and why I would not use MySQL BOOLEAN.

Answer (score 6):

Use `TINYINT(1)`. Allow `NULL` if you wish for the "not answered" option. You can also use `BOOLEAN` as it's just an alias for the aforementioned datatype. This way of storing boolean data is recommended by MySQL.

More details: [Which MySQL data type to use for storing boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/289727/388916)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the 0/1/null for No/Yes/Blank. 0 is always used as `false` and 1 for `true`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but in my system I use 1 as yes, 0 as no and just NO value as null - or if I have to specify I set a default value in the structure.

I think this system is more flexible, you can always manipulate with this data, for example if you don't want to display 0/1 values you can set something like

```
if(table.field == 1)
    echo yes;
else
    echo no;
```

Also comparing this value to any other database value is easier.

Answer (score 0):

as numbers are processed faster (while searching, sorting,..) by mysql, 
it takes less space in ur case, 
and also there are only 3 values (1, 0 nul
l)
 and in binary format ,1 and 0 have just one significant bit (0000000, & 0000001), the speed, in case of any comparisons, while traversing these columns, should remain higher and queries will take less time.

so i think u can go for first option.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) type is for. You can set your storage field type like this:

```
ENUM('no','yes')
```

and allow NULL as default value. If the answer is 'no' - the field value will actually be 0 (the index of 'no') and 1 if the answer is 'yes'. And you will have a nice representation of the column - 'yes' and 'no' instead of 1 and 0. Though the values will be actially stored as 0 and 1. I think its an advantage of using TINYINT.

Comment: After some digging though I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297149/enumyes-no-vs-tinyint-which-one-to-use. So it seems I am wrong. Voting up for tinyint.